# How to display a QForm inside the MainWindow with Qt?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I am trying to code a tree explorer GUI in Qt. On the left side, I have a tree view system which is handled by a Qt component `QTreeView`, but I would like that a form depending on the  selected tree element is displayed on the right panel. I cannot find a way to do it in Qt. I found an existing post about using a widget and promoting it to the form. That will certainly allow me to display ONE form inside the Qt `MainWindow` on the right panel but that's not going to allow me to change the form on the right panel each time a tree element is selected.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way using a `QScrollArea` and the function `setWidget` to dynamically displays a Qt Form in the main windows. Not ideal but works.